# Python Error - from libnames import _get_lib_name #@UnresolvedImport ImportError: No module named libnames

Tags: python, importerror

I am still new into the world of python and having some problems. I am working to compile `obspy-0.10.2` (might be old but all that is available) and get the following error when I run `python setup.py build`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 66, in <module>
     from libnames import _get_lib_name    # @UnresolvedImport
ImportError: No module named libnames.
```

I went into `setup.py` and looked at line 66 but could not think of a way to hard code the `libnames` as I am unaware of what that means. I have had to hardcode the line above to be `__version__ = '2.7.3'` for the python version.

Please correct me on the version number if it is wrong also but this `libnames` has been giving a hard time.

Comment: The latest obspy appears to be 1.0.2. Why are you compiling it, rather than just installing it with `pip`? Why do you think you need to modify the source or "hard code the libnames"? `libnames` is a module in that same library.

Comment: We are compiling from source so we can install to a different location. Pip is not installed and this is a stand alone network. Am I missing something for my path variables that is not allowing it to see libnames? Where would that module usually be? Sorry again I am new at pythong

Comment: It appears using help('modules') inside python I do not have libnames or version installed. That is weird.